# how to make gridview with imagebutton and duplicate image

Tags: java, android

does anyone know how to make gridview with image button? and when we click the image one from gridview, they make duplicate image and the image position at up gridview example app when i see is this one

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.widgit.widgitgo.lite

i think they use gridview with image button

i try making gridview, but i don't know how to make like that

please help

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is that you would like a gridview that displays an image on a different layout. You need to populate your gridview with the image you want, then I would use the setOnItemClickListener() method when an image is clicked on the gridview, and finally I would pass the image position as a reference to the upper layout (probably as a fragment).

This was a really concise explanation for your question, you will definitely find more hint on how to implement it here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry marco, do you have example source code, maybe i can see the code, because i m still new with android T_T thk where i can use android studio

Comment: Well Aditya, I'm really afraid to tell you that Android developing is pretty vast as a subject, and I don't know how much it would be helpful for you if I post the raw code without knowing what you would like to achieve in your project. I feel to suggest you to spend some time studying the resources that Google provide you on http://developer.android.com/ All the best